# Android lib ijkplayer load https url

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, ijkplayer

I am using ijkplayer in my android app that I compile using

```
compile 'tv.danmaku.ijk.media:ijkplayer-java:0.4.5'
compile 'tv.danmaku.ijk.media:ijkplayer-armv7a:0.4.5'
```

It works perfectly loading http urls but if I try to load https urls I get this error

```
https protocol not found, recompile FFmpeg with openssl, gnutls, or securetransport enabled.
```

and can't load my video. I don't know if it makes any difference but the url I am trying to load is a .m3u8 but if it is http works fine.

How can I recompile ffmpeg in this lib?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hi Petro i am not proffesional but hope this tutorial would help.

You have to compile ijkplayer with openssl support to open https links,
to do that follow this steps:

**Grab latest version of IjkPlayer from github:**

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer.git
```

Open just downloaded folder ijkplayer
Remove symlinks to module.sh and create symlink to module-lite.sh

```
$ cd config
$ rm module.sh
$ ln -s module-lite.sh module.sh
```

**Do initialisation of OpenSSL (getting ready to download and compile openssl first)**

```
$ cd ..
$ ./init-android-openssl.sh
```

Make sure you have pointed for your SDK and NDK path.

(NDK r10e preffered - I am not sure if SDK is needed but just in case i did exported it)

NOTE: make sure you have changed your path properly that is only example of path what i have used.

```
export ANDROID_SDK="/home/ZiomusGorliczanin/SDK"
export ANDROID_NDK="/home/ZiomusGorliczanin/NDK"
```

Open IjkPlayer/android/contrib folder and fire up compile-openssl.sh clean and all command (that will compile openssl for all processors).

```
$ cd android/contrib
$ ./compile-openssl.sh clean
$ ./compile-openssl.sh all
```

Compilation might take a while 10 min.

**Compile FFMpeg with OPENSSL for all processors:**

```
$ cd android/contrib
$ ./compile-ffmpeg.sh clean
$ ./compile-ffmpeg.sh all
```

**Finally compile IjkPlayer with all above as a liblary.**

```
$ cd ..
$ ./compile-ijk.sh all
```

After all this steps you should have liblaries in those folders (Three *.so files):

```
ijkplayer/ijkplayer-armv5/src/main/libs
ijkplayer/ijkplayer-armv7a/src/main/libs
ijkplayer/ijkplayer-arm64/src/main/libs
ijkplayer/ijkplayer-x86/src/main/libs
```

Try to import gradle project to your Android Studio and Run Ijk-Example for testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you got this error

> ./compile-ijk.sh profiler build: NO

It is because of security policy of Apple in MacBook, so there is alternative solution for this to go to `Apple menu-->System Preferences-->Security & Policy` and Allow anyway it will prompt there.

[image]